# postgresql insert into bytea field

Tags: postgresql

I have procedure:

```
create or replace function add_task( _g uuid, _name character varying, _ind bytea, _rate integer, _type integer )
returns void as 
$$
begin       
    insert into tasks (g, name, ind, rate, type) values (_g, _name, _ind, _rate, _type);    
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

I need to insert bytea field (_ind). The data is represented as bytes sequence and may be various.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> data = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
tr.exec("SELECT add_task_type('" + guid + "', '" + name + "', ......
```

How I can insert bytea field using SELECT string query?

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward way would be to use hex format.

```
SELECT E'\\xDEADBEEF';
```

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-binary.html#AEN5285